# How to set up a redirect to the desired text version of the site?

Tags: wordpress

I used qTranslate X plugin.
And plugin does not work on the redirect, given the language of the browser.
I use the plug-in setting by specifying the last point, 2 domain sites, one of which leads to a Russian site, the other to English.
so the redirects do not work for each other.

if you specify the use of the plug-in with the prefix /en/ and /ru/ then the redirects work at both sites normally.

Comment: This question is unclear.  What plugin are you using?  Have you checked the documentation for the plugin?

Comment: qTranslate X. yes I read documentation. but cant understand what a reason I have in my case. for to start something  do